# MSE or RSE, and how to interpret each?

Tags: regression, standard-error, mse

I'm on page 69 of ISLR 2nd Edition.
I've created a linear regression modeled after the toy dataset in the book, where we predict number of unit sales given a particular TV advertising budget.

Here are the linear regression results and its respective RSE and MSE:

[image]

I have 2 questions:

1. Do we use the RSE or the MSE to determine which is the best fitting linear regression and why?
2. In the book, it says since RSE = 3.26, it means actual sales in the market deviates from the true regression line on average by 3260 units (multiplied by 1000 due to conversion to per $1000 dollars of ad spend), which I understand. Well my MSE number is 24358.22 - how would this be interpreted? Pretty sure its not "actual sales in the market deviates from the true regression line on average by 24.3 million units"...

Comment: RSE is usually a metric to show how well the model has fitted the data together with R-squared though they have issues, and RSE is also used in prediction/forecast interval formula.